# Removing characters and reversing a string in python

Tags: python

I have to write a program where you put in two words and make an if statement for when the first word is the second word reversed and without the first and last characters. I have s2[1:-1:-1]==s but I don't understand how this doesn't work since s2[1:-1]==s works if I put in like lian and pliant. Also I have to write another program with a for loop and two splices to determine if a word is the same as another word if you remove one character. i.e. splender=slender. Any hints for this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to remember that the slice operator [start:finish] in Python goes from start to just before finish.  Consider the following:

```
>>>'hello'[1:-1]
'ell'
>>>'hello'[-2, 0, -1]
'lle'
```

When you're going backwards, you need to start from the other end.

Edit: alternatively, if you want to be a bit less clever you can just do

```
>>>'hello'[1:-1][::-1]
'lle'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def comp_words(longerW, shorterW):
    # compare if removing a char from first word can make it identical to second word
    return any(longerW[:i] + longerW[i+1:]  ==  shorterW for i, c in enumerate(longerW))
```